# High Chart Formatting

Tags: charts, highcharts, bar-chart, stacked-chart

```
vm.chartData = {
            'xAxis': [1512498600000, 1512585000000, 1512671400000, 1512757800000, 1512844200000, 1512930600000, 1513017000000, 1513103400000, 1513189800000, 1513276200000, 1513362600000, 1513449000000, 1513535400000, 1513621800000, 1513708200000, 1513794600000],
            'series': [{
                'name': 'Period 2',
                'data': [10, 2, 20, 40, 70, 40, 30, 33, 2, 23, 21, 32, 34, 12, 41, 21],
                'stack': 'Santanu N'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 3',
                'data': [30, 3, 1, 23, 10, 21, 14, 45, 65, 80, 10, 90, 52, 12, 42, 14],
                'stack': 'Sourav M'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 2',
                'data': [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 98, 87, 76, 65, 54, 43, 32, 21],
                'stack': 'Santanu N'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 3',
                'data': [21, 76, 43, 12, 22, 40, 50, 20, 70, 60, 10, 40, 20, 80, 20, 11],
                'stack': 'Sourav M'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 2',
                'data': [10, 2, 20, 40, 70, 40, 30, 33, 2, 23, 21, 32, 34, 12, 41, 21],
                'stack': 'Santanu NM'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 3',
                'data': [30, 3, 1, 23, 10, 21, 14, 45, 65, 80, 10, 90, 52, 12, 42, 14],
                'stack': 'Sourav MN'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 2',
                'data': [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 98, 87, 76, 65, 54, 43, 32, 21],
                'stack': 'Santanu NM'
            }, {
                'name': 'Period 3',
                'data': [21, 76, 43, 12, 22, 40, 50, 20, 70, 60, 10, 40, 20, 80, 20, 11],
                'stack': 'Sourav MN'
            }]
        };
```

Hello,
I want to show different colors for Period 1, Period 2 and Period 3. Now I am getting the different color for all the bar, I want to group these periods according to the different person. I'm stuck in chart representation need a better chart config.

Comment: is it a bar chart? if yes https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar here you can find the options provided for bar chart. or from here https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series you can find your chart and its options.

Comment: check this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Comment: I moved your example to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zhofw80z/ Is that the desired result?

Comment: @KamilKulig yea you are right, but one last thing in this example I,m getting 4 period2 and 4 period3. Instead of this, I need only 1 period2 and 1 period3 as chart legend. 
And if I click on period 2 legend the all the period 2 will be hidden or shown.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here seems to be to preprocess the series data (linking and coloring) like this:

```
 [{
    'name': 'Period 2',
    'data': [10, 2, 20, 40, 70, 40, 30, 33, 2, 23, 21, 32, 34, 12, 41, 21],
    'stack': 'Santanu N',
    id: 'p2'
  }, {
    'name': 'Period 3',
    'data': [30, 3, 1, 23, 10, 21, 14, 45, 65, 80, 10, 90, 52, 12, 42, 14],
    'stack': 'Sourav M',
    id: 'p3'
  },
  // other series
  {
    'name': 'Period 3',
    'data': [21, 76, 43, 12, 22, 40, 50, 20, 70, 60, 10, 40, 20, 80, 20, 11],
    'stack': 'Sourav MN'
  }].map(function(s, i) {
    switch (s.name) {
      case 'Period 2':
        s.color = 'red';
        if (i > 1) {
          s.linkedTo = 'p2'
        }
        break;
      case 'Period 3':
        s.color = 'blue';
        if (i > 1) {
          s.linkedTo = 'p3'
        }
        break;
    }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/zhofw80z/

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo